# Swapping limit at infinity with limit at 0

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to calculate:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)
$$

I am pretty sure that this is equivalent to calculating:

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(k)}{k}=1
$$

Since $k=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}k=0$.

Is there any way I can make this formal?

Comment: Looks sufficient to me.  Writing out a formal argument would I think add nothing of value. We do have to be a little careful, $k$ goes to $0$ **from the right**. That does not matter here, since the limit of $\frac{\sin k}{k}$  as $k$ approaches $0$ from either side is $1$.

Comment: There are probably many people (like one of my professors) who would demand a formal argument!

Comment: A matter of context. Early on in a *real analysis* course,  one likely would be expected to go through the $\epsilon$ routine. But soon even there one would reserve it for more serious matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have arrived at a formal argument using the definitions of limits.

Since $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow0}\dfrac{\sin(k)}{k}=1$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\left|\dfrac{\sin(k)}{k}-1\right|<\epsilon$ for all $|k-0|<\delta$.

Substituting $\dfrac{1}{x^2}=k$:

$$
\left|\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}-1\right|<\epsilon
$$

for all $\left|\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right|<\delta \Rightarrow \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\delta}}<x$ (since $\delta>0$, $x>0$).

Therefore for all $\epsilon>0$, 
$$
\left|\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}-1\right|<\epsilon
$$
for all $x>\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\delta}}>0$ for some $\delta>0$. Therefore, by the definition of a limit at infinity:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}=1$$

The limit at $-\infty$ could similarly be arrived at using the other half of the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is perfect !

**An other way :**

Since $$\sin\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\varepsilon(x)$$

where $\varepsilon(x)\to 0$ when $x\to\infty $, you get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty }x^2sin\frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\varepsilon(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to \infty }(1+\varepsilon(x))=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes,state $$k=\frac{1}{x^{2}}$$
Then we have, $$ x^2=\frac{1}{k}$$
As $x\rightarrow\infty$, $k\rightarrow0$ so, 
$$lim_{k\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(k)}{k}= 1$$
Since it is perfect!!
If you want to make it more formal simply use l'hospitals rule.